# Security in WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere

In WAS 6.1, when I click on Users and Groups --> Manage Users, I get error:

```
"You must enable administrative security and security must be activated to manage users and groups using the federated repositories feature."
```

How to go about solving this? I am new to WAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to [enable the administrative security](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_enablglobl.html). Typically this involves configuring your server against the file based registry or LDAP.